# Count of Employee Nos. starting with T and N

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Please help me solve this query. I want to find the count of employees where employee nos. starting with T and N from employee table which is grouped by District. The query is given below

```
select
    m.institution_dist,
    count(e.emp_pf_acc_number like 'T%') as tcnt,
    count(e.emp_pf_acc_number like 'N%') as ncnt 
from
    pf_emp e
    left join
    pfmast_institution m on e.emp_workplace_code = m.institution_code 
where
    e.retired <> 'Y'
    and emp_classification_code = '3'
    and m.institution_dist in (
        select dist_name
        from pfmast_dist
    )
group by m.institution_dist
```

The problem is that the result which I am getting is same for the employee no starting with both T and N.

Comment: And what is wrong with this query? Maybe if you give us some sample data and expected results, we may be able to help.

Comment: why not try the query for one like m.institution_dist ='dist1' rather than "m.institution_dist 
in(select dist_name from pfmast_dist)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `or null` to the count expression

```
count(e.emp_pf_acc_number like 'T%' or null) as tcnt,
count(e.emp_pf_acc_number like 'N%' or null) as ncnt
```

`count` counts not nulls. As your original expression returns either `true` or `false` it would always be counted. `false or null` evaluates to `null` so it is not counted.

There is an optimization to the `where` clause

```
and exists (
    select 1 
    from pfmast_dist
    where m.institution_dist = dist_name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query:

```
Select * from  

(select m.institution_dist, 
        Count(e.emp_pf_acc_number like 'T%') as tcnt  
from  pf_emp e 
left join   
pfmast_institution m     on e.emp_workplace_code = m.institution_code 
 where e.retired <> 'Y'    
 and emp_classification_code = '3'
 and m.institution_dist in ( select dist_name from pfmast_dist)
group by m.institution_dist ) x 

full outer join

(select b.institution_dist,count(a.emp_pf_acc_number like 'N%') as ncnt 
from pf_emp a
 left join
 pfmast_institution b on a.emp_workplace_code = b.institution_code 
 where b.retired <> 'Y'
 and emp_classification_code = '3'
 and b.institution_dist in ( select dist_name from pfmast_dist )
 group by b.institution_dist) y 
on x.institution_dist = y.institution_dist
```